# Test my website online

Tags: testing

How can I test my website online (before it is public) and that no one can see it except me?

I know I can add a password but I don't want that google indexs it (before it's really public).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how your website is designed (PHP, Python, Ruby), you would have to establish a web server.  The most typical configuration is [AMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29), which stands for Apache, MySQL, and PHP/Python.  (Typically this runs atop Linux, but it can be run under Windows too.)

Ruby on Rails comes with its own built-in web server.  Most Python web frameworks (Django, CherryPy, Pylons) do too.

Comment: Thanks! And in MAMP, can I put the `.htaccess`?

Comment: If you're using Apache, then yes, you can use .htaccess files.  Be careful though, there are some pitfalls to configuring those properly.

Comment: I don't think that I will be able to test completely because, for example, of the `RewriteRule` for `WWW` or `non-WWW`.

Answer (score 3):

To prevent google from indexing it, use this meta tag in your head:
`<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />`
This tells search engines you do not wish for your page to show up in the search results.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `robots.txt` file to your website.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Save the text above into a text file called `robots.txt`, and upload it to your website root.

By using this, any well-behaved crawler will not read your website, and any well-behaved search engine not index your website.